# Using Evil mode with SLIME

Tags: emacs, slime

I'd really like to get up and running with a great Lisp REPL, but unfortunately I'm a vim person, not an emacs person.  Is there a way to configure Emacs so that I can use slime while in Evil mode?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you have Evil-mode always enabled `(evil-mode 1)`, you can still use it in  slime.

Comment: Unfortunately though Evil disables the M-x shortcut, so I can't launch slime.

Comment: @jeffythedragonslayer here is a related [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28703799/1210633) on how to enable `M-x` shortcut with Evil-mode. Currently I'm using [evil-leader](https://github.com/cofi/evil-leader) which IMO is easier than `M-x` shortcut.

Comment: isn't `M-x` the same as `:` in evil-mode? `:slime` worked for me (stole my buffer though).